# Finding demonstration of a formula used for calculating Laguerre integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, laguerre-polynomials

does someone know where i can find the mathematical demonstration of this formula?

http://functions.wolfram.com/05.08.21.0009.01

I honestly dont even know what to search for on the internet, seems a very niche formula, personally i thought that maybe it could be derived by expressing the Laguerre polynomials as sums and integrating term by term?

If you have a place where theres the demonstration please link it to me.